# BlazorServer security

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have create a blazor server project.

I have wrote this razor page in order to understand how blazor works:

```
@page "/"

<div>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="input_password" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
    <button @onclick="@(() => check_password())">Check password</button>
</div>

<div>
    @display_secret
</div>

@code{
    private String input_password;
    private String display_secret;

    private async void check_password()
    {
        if (input_password == "1234")
        {
            display_secret = "Well done: Here is a secret: bla bla bla";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, user should type a password. If this password is good, a secret phrase is displayed to the user.

Is there a way for an hacker to see the secret phrase without typing the good password ?

I do not understand what is done on server side and what is done in browser.
Is my C# code translated into javascript ? And if so, is it possible to see the secret phrase in browser's developper tools ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Blazor Server project your code inside `@code` or code behind files isn't translated in JS and sent to the client *before* the execution.
Your code is executed on the server and the DOM parts to update are sent to the browser via Signalr.
The browser use JS to apply the DOM modifications.

Your

```
input_password == "1234"
```

will never reside into client code.
If you add some code to javascript files it will be sent to the client, like any standard web page.

**Blazor WASM**

In Blazor WASM the approach is different, because the code inside the razor components is (pre)compiled into Webassembly and sent to the client browser.
Every logic is inside the webassembly code and resides on the client.

Comment: And is there a way to do the same thing in javascript ? (my goal is to understand if i can accidentally do something that will be translated in js) Thanks

Comment: in Blazor Server JS is sent via JS files referenced in the _Host.cshtml or per component, or tag that you explicit insert into the razor component as "text".
I've added some info to the answer.